Identify this movie infectious disease 2005-2010
This movie is only a blurry memory for me, so it might not all be correct.
I watched it when I was younger, and I remember thinking it was pretty scary and gross. I am fairly sure it is a found footage film, with a group of adults. The one scene i remember in particular is of a girl, with messy dark hair, becoming sick with the disease. She is removed from the group by quarantine officers, and I remember that you were able to see her throw up a large amount of blood on a white hanging hospital-esque cloth. 
I am also fairly sure that it had something to do with aliens, and was set in the US. The movie also seemed new, 2005-2010. It was also in English.
I know that it is not much to go own, but maybe someone knows!

You are looking for Cloverfield

The film is presented as found footage from a personal video camera recovered by the United States Department of Defense. 
  [...] They get caught in a battle between the monster and the National Guard before running into the Spring Street station, where they are attacked by several of the parasite creatures inside the subway tunnel. Marlena is attacked and bitten by one of the creatures. They enter the 59th Street station, where they exit the subway. They come across a command center and field hospital, where Marlena dies from the bite

The scene with the blood (not from vomiting but from exploding) can be seen here - warning gory images (around 2:12):




Your are welcome, please mark the question as answered.
